# this and function in JavaScript an jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

I want to write a JavaScript function and invoke it on a this object in this way:

```
<div id= 'MyDiv'>screamer</div>

function scream()
{
   if(this.hasClass("scream")) {
      alert("scream");
   }
   else {
      alert("shhhh");
   }
}
$(function () {
   $('#MyDiv").scream();
```

}

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JtN9W/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you want to create a jQuery plugin. Read this: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/. There are other problems though, e.g. you are using mismatched quotation marks: `$('#MyDiv")`.

Comment: you can also give a try to book [**Extending JQuery**](http://www.amazon.com/Extending-jQuery-Keith-Wood/dp/161729103X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
jQuery.fn.scream = function() {
    if(this.hasClass("scream")) {
        alert("scream");
    } else {
        alert("shhhh");
    }
}  
$(function () {
     $('#MyDiv').scream();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JtN9W/2/.

Answer (score 4):

`scream` is a global, so it is a property of the `window` object and not the `jQuery` object that you've created.

If you want to [attach it to every jQuery instance](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) then you need to assign it to `$.fn.something`

```
function scream() {
    //etc
}
$.fn.scream = scream;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are more error:

1. I change you code with replace ' to " but you can use also this character '
2. The function scream you can't call with jquery using `$('#MyDiv").scream();`
   I change this in

   ```
    $(function () {
          scream($("#MyDiv"));});
   ```

And I don't know how to use this call $('#MyDiv").scream(); and I change your code passing the `div`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/JtN9W/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own object, follow jQuery api manual: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

**Solution for you:**

```
(function ( $ ) 
{
  $.fn.scream = function() 
  {
    var c = $(this);

   if(c.hasClass("scream")) {
      alert("scream");
   }
   else {
      alert("shhhh");
   }

    return this;
  };

}( jQuery ));

$(function () {
   $('#scream').scream();
     });
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<div id="scream" class="screaam"></div>
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qPgA9/

Cheers!